# As a file hosting provider, how do you prevent phishing?

Tags: security, cloud-storage, phishing, virus-scanning

We develop a service much like Dropbox or Google Drive or S3 where our customers can host their files and get direct links to them with our domain, e.g. `www.ourservice.com/customer_site/path/to/file`.
Recently we started receiving emails from our server provider that we host phishing `.html` files. It appeared that some of our customers did host such htmls and of course we removed the files after that and blocked the customers.
But the problem is that we would like to prevent this from happening at all, mainly because this lowers our Google Search index and of course we never wanted to be a hosting for phishing scripts.
Is there a way how other file hosting providers solve this? I guess we could run some checks (anti-virus, anti-phishing etc.) when the customers upload their files, but that would be pretty tedious considering that there's a lot of them. Another options is to periodically check all the files, or all new files, but still I'd better ask if I'm missing any easier solution.